# I am having trouble downloading a python file from my jupyter notebook

Tags: python, google-chrome, download, jupyter-notebook

I am having trouble downloading a python file from my jupyter notebook.

I get this image when I try to download from chrome.

[image]

Any ideas on how to resolve>

Comment: Click on `•••` and click `keep`